# Changing height of leading/trailingSwipeActions on a custom table cell

Tags: ios, swift, uiswipegesturerecognizer, swipe-gesture

I'm currently developing a Swift 4 iOS application. I have a custom table cell that is displayed in a card view (see example screenshot below).

When I implement SwipeActions on a row, the height of the background color of the swipe menu takes up the full height of the cell row.

I'd like for it to be just the height of the card view. I should add that each row is a different height as they contain small pieces of text of varying length. Is there a way to achieve this?

[image: Example of card view]

Comment: I think there is no way, you can change height. But as an alternate solution to it, add swipe gesture on card layout and upon swipe open another view according to your design requiremnt

Comment: You can't do that with native, I already tried. you can search on github may be there any code available that do same thing as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks folks — I just discovered [SwipeCellKit](https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit) that allows a better level of customization. It doesn't fix the row height problem but I think I can overcome it by setting the swipe background color to that of the view controller and use colorful icons/text for the swipe actions (the customized 'Expansion Style' in SwipeCellKit).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This isn't possible. Find an alternative approach for customization.

Answer (score 2):

Exists an alternative to do this. You can change size, but it is old mode like change height `(view.size.height= (newvalue))`. To change position use `(view.frame.origin.y = (newvalue))`. It will work in static height cell and iOS >=11. This will not work in dynamic height cells. Make these changes inside the delegate method of tableviewcell

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? TempcellTableViewCell{
            if let spvcell = cell.superview{
                for svswipe in spvcell.subviews{
                    let typeview = type(of: svswipe.self)
                    if typeview.description() == "UISwipeActionPullView"{
                        svswipe.frame.size.height = 100//size you want
                        svswipe.frame.origin.y = 5
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }
```

and in functions of `leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt/trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt`. Make following changes before it return UISwipeActionsConfiguration object.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let Cancel = UIContextualAction.init(style: .normal, title: "Cancel") { (action, view, nil) in
             print("Cancel")
         }
         Cancel.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

         let config = UISwipeActionsConfiguration.init(actions: [Cancel])
         config.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false // Prevent swiping

         tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)

         return config
    }
```

This solution worked for me :D ... I hope this answer can help you

Answer (score 1):

And what if all the cells in the application are written using UIEdgeInsets with top and bottom? And you need to implement a swipe action of the desired height. I hope the answer will help someone.

Advantages of this method, no need to calculate the height of the cell (suitable for a dynamic cell).

1. Add in extension UITableViewCell this UIView and method. Set this parameters of cell, as top and bottom.

   ```
   extension UITableViewCell {

      var cellActionPullView: UIView? {
       superview?.subviews
        .filter{ String(describing: $0).range(of: "UISwipeActionPullView") != nil }
        .compactMap { $0 }.first
      }

      func setRemoveSwipeAction() {
         cellActionPullView?.snp.makeConstraints({ make in
         make.top.equalTo(self.snp.top).offset(8)
         make.bottom.equalTo(self.snp.bottom).inset(8)})
      }

   }
   ```
2. Add in your cell:

   ```
   override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    setRemoveSwipeAction()
   }

   override func layoutIfNeeded() {
    super.layoutIfNeeded()
    setRemoveSwipeAction()
   }
   ```
3. Add in your VC leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt or trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt.
4. Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on PollyVern [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73296315/22457245), this is what works for me.

1. Add in the extension UITableViewCell this UIView and method. Set the height and origin y.

```swift
extension UITableViewCell {    
    var cellActionPullView: UIView? {
        superview?.subviews
            .filter{ String(describing: $0).range(of: "UISwipeActionPullView") != nil }
            .compactMap { $0 }.first
    }
    
    func setRemoveSwipeAction() {
        cellActionPullView?.frame.size.height = self.frame.height - 8
        cellActionPullView?.frame.origin.y = 8
    }
}
```

2. Add to your tableview cell

```swift
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    setRemoveSwipeAction()
}
        
override func layoutIfNeeded() {
    super.layoutIfNeeded()
    setRemoveSwipeAction()
}
```

3. Result:

[image: here]